# Specifying Values in D3 Graph from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to get values from the "links" instead of "nodes. I guess a more helpful way of asking this is how to specify where I am requesting getting the values from my JSON.

JSON for reference:

```
{
"nodes": [
{"fixed":true,"data": {"id": "foo","idType":"USERNAME","color":"red"},"selected":false},
{"fixed":true,"data": {"id": "bar","idType":"USERNAME","color":"yellow"},"selected": false}
],
"links": [
{"classes":null,"data":{"color":"blue","source":"foo","target":"bar","visible":true},"grabbable":false},
{"classes":null,"data":{"color":"green","source":"bar","target":"foo","visible":true},"grabbable":false}
]}
```

So an example is I can get this to work

```
node.style("fill", function(d) { return d.data['color'] });
```

but not

```
link.style("stroke", function(d) { return d.data['color'] });
```

However, this works...

```
link.style("stroke", "red"});
```

In the console it says d.data['color'] is undefined. I guess I do not understand how it is being called exactly. I have seen some examples of code that has

```
function(d, i) { return bla bla }
```

and I assumed that if d is always node, maybe i might be edges but adding that to my code didn't do much. If someone could explain what the i is touching that would be good also.

Code snippet of actual code below:

```
// Define the dimensions of the visualization.
var width = innerWidth,
    height = innerHeight,
    color = d3.scale.category20(),
    root;

// Create an array logging what is connected to what
var linkedByIndex = { };

// Create the SVG container for the visualization and define its dimensions
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

// Create the force layout
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(-400)
    .linkDistance(50);

//Read in the JSON data.
d3.json("../test/resources/full.json", function(error, json) {
    // expands scope of json
    root = json
    alert(root)
    update();
});

function update() {

// sets the source and target to use id instead of index
var edges = [];
root.links.forEach(function(e) {
    var sourceNode = root.nodes.filter(function(n) {
                return n.data.id === e.data.source;
            })[0],
            targetNode = root.nodes.filter(function(n) {
                return n.data.id === e.data.target;
            })[0];

    edges.push({
        source: sourceNode,
        target: targetNode
    });
});

force
        .nodes(root.nodes)
        .links(edges)
        .start();

link = link
        .data(edges)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link");

node = node
        .data(root.nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
    //.attr("fixed", function(d) { return d.fixed=true })
        .call(force.drag)
        .on('mouseover', connectedNodes)
        .on('mouseleave', restore)
        .on('click', highlight);

// Checks for the shape and color to be made for the node.
node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 10);

node.style("fill", function(d) { return d.data['color'] });
link.style("stroke", function(d) { return d.data['color'] }); 

node.append("text")
        .attr("dx", 12)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("fill", "black")
    // Checks what to return as the node label based on idType.
        .text(function (d) {
            if (d.data['idType']==="Comment") {
                return d.data.attrs[1].val;
            }
            else if(d.data['idType']==="MEDIA") {
                return "MEDIA " + d.data['id'];
            }
            else
                return d.data['id'];
        });

root.links.forEach(function (d) {
    linkedByIndex[d.data.source + "," + d.data.target] = 1;
});

resize();
window.addEventListener('resize', resize);

}
```

Comment: Links have a source and a target node, so you could do `link.style("stroke", function(d) { return d.source.data['color'] });` or `link.style("stroke", function(d) { return d.target.data['color'] });`.

Comment: Hmmm but that would utilize the nodes colors. What if I have the color set in the links data portion of the JSON? with ref JSON: `link.data.['color']`

Comment: Well it sounds like you're not using that data for the links -- can you post the code you're using please?

Comment: I've added a snippet of the code that I am using.

Comment: Right, you're not using the data for the links at all -- if you want to do that, you need to take account of it when putting together `edges`.

Comment: isn't that what this line does: `link = link.data(edges)` ?

Comment: I don't see that line anywhere.

Comment: It is after the whole `force.etc.etc.start()` but before `node.data`

Comment: Oh yes of course. But `edges` doesn't contain the original link data.

Comment: So I just have to set another variable like `var linkData = link.data(root.links)`? Cause I ran and tested the console.log and it indeeds outputs the correct color however, if I do that I will not be able to link my nodes by ID. Thus, my graph breaks.

Comment: Nevermind, I see what you are saying! In my `edges.push` I just had to add `color = e.data['color']`. Thank you for your help Lars!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Lars' comment, edges does not contain the original link data. So it was currently pushing only

```
edges.push({
    source: sourceNode,
    target: targetNode
});
```

so to add any information that isn't in my edges I would have to add it. An example is if I were to push the color attribute from JSON my code would look like

```
edges.push({
    source: sourceNode,
    target: targetNode,
    color: e.data['color']
});
```